# Stop a div scrolling once its content finishes, while the other div keeps scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want that the col-md-4 column to stop scrolling once it finishes the content (like the right sidebar from facebook). I already tried something with jquery (to add a position fixed when it reach the bottom but it's not working)
col-md-4 - stop scrolling one the content finishes
col-md-8 - keep scrolling

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <div class="col-md-4 scrollFunc">
                <?php require 'includes/profile/description.php'; ?>
                <?php require 'includes/profile/photos.php'; ?>

                <div class="well"><h1>asd</h1></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left: 5px !important;">
            <?php require 'includes/profile/posts.php'; ?>
            <div id="displayPosts">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the reason I have the class scrollFunc:

```
  $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 226) {
                $(".scrollFunc").addClass("fixed");
                console.log('asdad');
            } else {
                $(".scrollFunc").removeClass("fixed");
            }
    });
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlZs1.png
After the asd well it should stop.

Comment: Where is the corresponding css?

Comment: I don't have anything in the scrollFunc class. I used that for a jquery function.

Comment: Try using `position: absolute` instead of using `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an idea about how you can integrate using bootstrap affix plugin. And you have to redesign for the mini devices.

```js
$('#myAffix').affix({
  offset: {
    top: 100,
    bottom: function () {
      return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="leftside" id="myAffix">
      Left fixed side
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="well well-sm">Right Side</div>
    <div class="well well-sm">Right Side</div>
    <div class="well well-sm">Right Side</div>
    <div class="well well-sm">Right Side</div>
    <div class="well well-sm">Right Side</div>
    <div class="well well-sm">Right Side</div>
    <div class="well well-sm">Right Side</div>
    <div class="well well-sm">Right Side</div>
    <div class="well well-sm">Right Side</div>
    <div class="well well-sm">Right Side</div>
    <div class="well well-sm">Right Side</div>
  </div>
</div>
```